# Asynchronous function call in C# 4.0

Tags: multithreading, winforms, c#-4.0

Good day. In my application there is a treeview and the nodes indicate the data to connect via tcp. I want the display of these connections to start when the form is displayed.

I added an asynchronous function, but it comes to my check and its execution ends.

```
 public async void checkConnect()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < treeView1.Nodes.Count; i++)
        {
            string result = await Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() => connectTread(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        }
    }

public string connectTread()
    {
        string ret = "";
        string[] IpHERE;

        foreach (TreeNode child in treeView1.Nodes)
        {
            IpHERE = child.Text.Split(' ');
            Modbus mb = new Modbus();
            Regex regIP = new Regex(@"\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b");

            if (regIP.IsMatch(IpHERE[1]) && IpHERE[1].Length != 0 && IpHERE[4].Length != 0 && IpHERE[9].Length != 0 && IpHERE[11].Length != 0 && (mb.OpenTCP(IpHERE[1], IpHERE[4], IpHERE[9], IpHERE[11])))
            {
                child.SelectedImageIndex = 3;

                mb.CloseTCP();
                ret = "Ok";
            }
            else
            {
                child.SelectedImageIndex = 4;
                ret = "Error";
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: `async void` is a bug. It's only meant for event handlers because it *can't* be awaited. Any tasks started inside it are `fire-and-forget` and probably garbage collected before they have a chance to finish, or even start

Answer (score 0):

> I want the display of these connections to start when the form is displayed.

When the form is first displayed, you must display the data immediately. You should *initialize* the display with some kind of a "Loading..." value or spinner or something, and *start* the asynchronous operation(s) when the form is displayed.

Then, later, when the asynchronous operation(s) complete, then *update* the data in the form with the actual data.

P.S. [Avoid `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) and [use `Task.Run` instead of `StartNew`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).